# How to suppress a MongoDDException when proxy can't find a referenced document

Tags: doctrine-odm

We are using Symfony2/DoctrineOdm/MongoDB and when we do:

`if ($doc.referenceOne != null) { ... }`

and the `$doc.referenceOne` contains a **MongoDbRef** that point to a deleted/lost document, the Doctrine Proxy object raises a MongoDBException.

It is possible to tell the Proxy return null instead of raising the exception?

---

**Detailed Explanation:**

Our document:

```
class User {
    /* @MongoDB\ReferenceOne( ... ) */
    private $photo;
}
```

If $photo contains a **MongoDbRef**, but the document is lost/deleted,

when we do `if ($user.photo) { ... }` doctrine will raise a MongoDBException:

```
The "Proxies\DocumentPhotoProxy" document with identifier "4fd8b3ef732bafab7b000000" could not be found
```

We want to suppress the exception since our application can handle null values in that variable.

(we could simply log that error, while the exception propagate to a 500 page and disrupt our service)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2:** Doctrine extensions reference integrity can also help. It nullifies the invalid reference automatically. You can find more information on their GitHub repository: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/reference_integrity.md and for Symfony2 integration: https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle

**Edit:** I couldn't understand if you were referring to twig templates or php. Below you will find a solution for twig but if your question is about php adding a `try...catch` block for your getter might help you fix the problem.

I don't know if you have already found a solution but in case if anyone else needs this I've used a (dirty) work around:

Overwrite `Twig_Template` class by defining a custom one in your main configuration file (`config.yml`)

Example:

```
# app/config/config.yml
base_template_class: Acme\DemoBundle\Template
```

And overwrite the `getAttribute` method with a `try...catch` block:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentNotFoundException;

abstract class Template extends \Twig_Template
{
    protected function getAttribute($object, $item, array $arguments = array(), $type = \Twig_TemplateInterface::ANY_CALL, $isDefinedTest = false, $ignoreStrictCheck = false)
    {
        try {
            $ret = parent::getAttribute($object, $item, $arguments, $type, $isDefinedTest, $ignoreStrictCheck);
        } catch (DocumentNotFoundException $e) {
            $ret = null;
        }
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

This will ignore all DocumentNotFoundExceptions.

**Be careful though**, invalid references are still there in your database. This only ignores the exception thrown in your twig templates.

Comment: I was looking for a solution in both php and twig, but surely in php I can use a try...catch, while your solution for the twig part is great! I'll still look around for a definitive solution, for eg: a way to change the autogenerated proxy so that it will suppress the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Only add "sort"

instead of

```
/**
 * @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Extra", simple=true)
 */
private $extras;
```

use

```
/**
 * @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Extra", simple=true, sort={"name"="asc"})
 */
private $extras;
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem was with ReferenceOne, with ReferenceMany doctrine ODM return an ArrayList, that can be empty. While with ReferenceOne, if the target document isn't found, an exception si raised.

Comment: This could help in some cases. In my case, it's important to keep the sequence of elements intact, so this approach would not work for me. But a quite simple hack this is.

Answer (score 0):

you should add this annotation "mappedBy" in your document

```
/**
 * @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Extra", mappedBy="....")
 */
private $extras;
```